# How can I stick something to the screen with responsive CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a fintech application and I am using a mockup from an already existing application as my own UI. I need it to look as professional as possible. I have a bit of a problem though. My application has a card in one of the sections. On PC, it looks fine but it moves out from its original position on mobile. I have added media queries but they are not helping.

It's my codes:

```css
  .card-container {
  position: relative;
}

.card-tip {
  width: 290px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(223, 186, 129, 0.6);
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.card-tip span {
  width: 250px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #8F6524;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateY(6px);
}

.card {
  width: 260px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 40.5%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(32, 30, 30, 0.3);
  transform: translateY(-9px);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
```

```html
<section id="feature-section">
  <h1>It's free to send money</h1>
  <p>It costs nothing to send money, when you link your Paga wallet to your bank account.</p>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card-tip">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h6>Your receipt</h6>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
      <p>₦<span>0</span>.00</p>
      <h6>No transfer fee</h6>
      <h6>No 'convenience' fee</h6>
      <h6>No hidden charge</h6>
      <img src="images/rocket.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The completed web page can also be locked viewed through this link: https://chinomso1995.github.io/mini-fintech-application.

Just click on send money. Its the first link Item.

The card shifts on mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not right to use margin-left to center items. You can use margin: auto to center items exactly.If you use margin-left to average items with each other, you will have to adjust them all again for each size ( tablet, mobile). a method is not correct.

I also used the display:flex structure to bring the card down and down without overflow.

No matter what size they are, there will be no overflow because I use Display flex.

```css
.card-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
}

.card-tip {
  width: 290px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(223, 186, 129, 0.6);
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.card-tip span {
  width: 250px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #8F6524;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateY(6px);
}

.card {
  width: 260px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #000234;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(32, 30, 30, 0.3);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
```

```html
<section id="feature-section">
  <h1>It's free to send money</h1>
  <p>It costs nothing to send money, when you link your Paga wallet to your bank account.</p>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card-tip">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h6>Your receipt</h6>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
      <p>₦<span>0</span>.00</p>
      <h6>No transfer fee</h6>
      <h6>No 'convenience' fee</h6>
      <h6>No hidden charge</h6>
      <img src="images/rocket.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```